# How to set the default Column subclass that SQLAlchemy's autoload should use?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am subclassing some of SQLAlchemy's classes to provide additional functionality.

I have already a database, and sometimes, just for speed, I use autoload.

I have made it work with queries:

```
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, query_cls=MyCustomQueryClass)
```

I want to do the same with `MyCustomColumnClass`, but cannot find how. In other words, tell autoload which class to use for autoloaded columns, and somehow make this work:

```
class MyCustomColumnClass(Column):
    pass

class SomeTable(Base):
    __table__ = sqlalchemy.schema.Table('some_table',
                                        Base.metadata, 
                                        autoload=True)

# SomeTable autoloads its columns, so next line return True
isinstance(SomeTable.some_autoloaded_column, MyCustomColumnClass)
```

Comment: is "column_name" like a mapped column?  that's not supported (it's likely possible but would not be that easy to work out).  you'd need to find some other route to what you want, I'd suggest [attribute events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/events.html#attribute-events), or any of the other techniques introduced at [changing attribute behavior](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/mapper_config.html#changing-attribute-behavior).

Comment: `column_name` is the name of a column in `Table`. Maybe it's not enough clear, but see the `autoload=True`.

Comment: OK so the actual schema.Column(), not the attribute on the mapped class "Table" (sorry, those are two different things...).  yeah that's not really supported either.   schema.Table/Column are not good targets for subclassing, there's lots of other ways to add behavior to them though, events is a big one, custom types/operators, etc.   your use case for what you want to do with Column is the important part here, there's probably another way to do what you want.

Comment: @zzzeek I want to add an .html() method to return a controller.

Comment: you can extend the operators on a datatype, is this "html" thing specific to some data type like String?   see http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/types.html#types-operators

Comment: @zzzeek no, it's more like generating an <input/> that shows the field information when querying.

Comment: I don't really understand, please amend the question with a specific example of usage and what the output would be.

Comment: I updated the question. Let me know if you understand now, please. Thanks a lot.

Comment: not really.   we're looking here for a way for you to get what you want without the need to subclass Column.  Column is not easy to subclass and reflection doesn't really have support for what you want to do.  If your use case is valid and has absolutely no other way for it to work, then this would need to be a feature add.   But I'd prefer to work out your use case some other way and for that I need a usage example.